# Why isn't my html responding?

Tags: html

My html doesn't show any content that I wrote.
The objective that I'm trying to accomplish is to make a button on the right "div" to make a random joke out of 5 spawn on the left div. The problem is that I don't know how to make a function to make the button spawn a joke. The joke would be in a separate html which I will use to replace the default one in the left div when you load the html.
I'm sorry if that's really incoherently confusing, but thank you for committing.

This is what I have so far:

The primary html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Free Jokes!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="final project.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head> 

<body>
<h1 id="shadow">Welcome to Free Jokes!</h1>
<div id="left" src="left.html"/>
<div id="right" src="right.html"/>
</body>
</html>
```

The left div html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Free Jokes!</title>
        <script>
        var randomnumber

        function clickForJoke() {
        randomnumber=math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * 5);

        switch ( randomnumber ) {
        case 1:
            window.open( "joke1.html", target="right" );
            break;
        case 2:
            window.open( "joke2.html", target="right" );
            break;
        case 3:
            window.open( "joke3.html", target="right" );
            break;
        case 4:
            window.open( "joke4.html", target="right" );
            break;
        case 5:
            window.open( "joke5.html", target="right" );
            break;

        default:
            window.open( "joke.html", target="right" );
```

and the external css:

```
body
{
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#shadow
{
    text-shadow: -5px -8px 2px lightgreen;
    font-size: 600%;
}

left
{
    float:left;width:30%;
}

right
{
    float:right;width:70%;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, your CSS selectors are wrong. They should be:

```
body
{
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#shadow
{
    text-shadow: -5px -8px 2px lightgreen;
    font-size: 600%;
}

#left
{
    float:left;width:30%;
}

#right
{
    float:right;width:70%;
}
```

Secondly, you can't use the `src` attribute on a `div` tag. That makes no sense!

If you're trying to include content into the page from somewhere else, you need to use an `iframe` tag. Regardless of my feelings towards using this, it should be more like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Free Jokes!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="final project.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head> 

<body>
<h1 id="shadow">Welcome to Free Jokes!</h1>
<iframe id="left" src="left.html"></iframe>
<iframe id="right" src="right.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Good luck!

Comment: @mishik What's wrong with W3Schools? You may not like that website, but the information on that page is useful enough to illustrate the point. Also, the link is an addition to the answer, not reliant on it - so even if link rot did occur, it would be a moot point.

Comment: Even though _some_ information on w3schools is okay. There's still a large portion of deviation from standards and sometimes even information that contradicts actual w3c data. Please check the link from my comment above: http://w3fools.com

Comment: @mishik I don't believe that w3schools are claiming to be affiliated with the w3c. Even so, whilst it is sometimes inaccurate, I wouldn't say that any resource out there is without its mistakes. Use it with a pinch of salt...but it's not completely useless!

Comment: I never said they are affiliated with w3c. They are not. But they are "teaching" bad things to junior and not-so-junior developers. And the problem is not with the amount of inaccuracy of the site, the problem is that you never know if the information you're looking at is correct. You just can't trust it. If a knowing person sees an article and know that it's wrong - he/she will just look away, but newbie will trust it. And there is no way that community can actually improve w3schools content. Thus, a huge amount of crappy upcoming applications are crappy because of w3schools.

Comment: @mishik Hopefully that's why they're here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that

```
<div id="left" src="left.html"/> //src not allowed inside div tag
```

Use `Iframe` instead.

`Iframe` are used for that purpose i.e. to include another `html` page in the body.And you can very well enclose `Iframe` inside `div`

visit [this](http://manda.com/iframe)  for a good tutorial on Iframes.